# How to get a layout like this in flexbox

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, grid

Hi I have been asked to create a layout on a page that looks like the attached image:

[image: Image of layout]

What would be the best way to achieve this? Flexbox? CSS Grid ?

Any code help would be great as don't really want have to use a messy page builder

Thanks

Comment: you can get it by reading some tutorial about flexbox and you will get two things : you learnt a new technique + this layout

Comment: Not the most helpful of answers !

I have had a look but never really seen this on any other websites could you care to share any resources that may help ? Thanks

Comment: of course you will never see this :) but if you learn the basics you will be able to do this ... you don't have to find website that will show you how to do THIS EXACT layout, you have to understand how you can do such layout

Comment: Okay thanks very much :)

Comment: by the way better look for bootstrap, the suitable solution for beginner as you learn without too much of code

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this

Believe I have found what I was looking for here

https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/#setup

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container > div {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 35px;
}
```